# Is there any way to highlight text in evince by selecting the given text?

Tags: 20.04, pdf

In Windows as Adobe Reader provides a way by which we can highlight the given text by just selecting the text. Is there any way to do same in evince in Linux?

UPD: I want to ask is there any auto highlight property present in Evince. Instead of using Ctrl+H etc.

Answer (score 2):

Select the text using your mouse, right click with the mouse and select `Highlight`
You can save the text with the highlight.

Once selected, reselect the text and you can select `Annotation Properties` if you wish to, for example, *change the colour of the highlight or *Strike out or underline* the text instead.

You can resave the document with the new settings.